# Call JS function on form submit before http request occurs

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics

I want to pass a selected checkbox value, when a user submits (`POSTs`) a form, to Google Analytics to track as a custom metric within Google Analytics dashboard.

The user will submit their choice to the server which will first call the JS `sendDataToGA(selectedOption) {` function to pass that data to GA, then the POST will run.

How do I accomplish this? It seems that the `POST` is firing and not calling the JS function.

**PHP/HTML:**

```
    <?php if (!empty($_POST)): ?>
        Selection: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($_POST["option"]); ?><br>

    <?php else: ?>
        <!-- On form submit, fire a custom GA function to capture the selected option -->
        <form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> method="post" > 
          <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="option 1">Option 1<br>
          <input type="checkbox" name="option" value="option 2">Option 2<br>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitBtn" onclick="sendDataToGA(selectedOption);">
        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**JS:**

```
function sendDataToGA(selectedCheckboxValue) {
    ga('send', 'event', 'category', 'action', {
        'metric1': selectedCheckboxValue,
            'hitCallback': function () {
            console.log("data has been sent to Google Analytics");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give your form an id attribute you can do the following using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

```
$("#myForm").submit(function () {
    ga(...);
});
```

or without jQuery:

```
<form action=<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?> onsubmit="sendDataToGA(selectedOption)" method="post"> 
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: It says `sendDataToGA` function is not defined

Comment: Are you correctly importing the JS file in your HTML? Could you provide some more code?

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept the submit event before it posts to the server. In jQuery, this is a handler you attach in the domReady event. This assumes your form has id="formid", and you can halt the postback by setting everythingIsOkay = false.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#formid").submit(function(event) { //Catch form submit event
        event.preventDefault(); //Stop it from posting back unless you tell it to
        var everythingIsOkay = true;
      
        //Do your processing here
      
        if(everythingIsOkay){
            document.forms["formid"].submit(); //Go ahead and postback
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but I am not using jQuery in my app

Comment: Simple enough, you should be able to use the onsubmit tag with the same function:  onsubmit="function(event) { ... }"